# Make a multi-page print job in Java

Tags: java, printing

How do I make a multi Page print job in Java. I am using the import java.awt.print.Printable; package, and I can only manage to print 1 page at a time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [Pageable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Pageable.html), not Printable.